# Disabling bone101 on BeagleBone Black

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I have a BeagleBone black running Debian.
Using "htop" I see a number of processes consuming a decent amount of memory      `"/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/jekyll buld --destination bone101 --watch"`
I don't need the bone101 service for my application and would like to disable it. "`systemctl disable bone101.service`" return a "`no such file or directory`" error.
I can kill the process manually in htop but would like for it to not run on startup. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

you can disable it with:

```
systemctl disable jekyll-autorun.service
```

stop the bone script using:

```
systemctl disable bonescript-autorun.service
```